# Is there any time trace web application?

Tags: performance, monitoring

Is there any time trace web application?

I want use it as a tool for monitor my program productivity.(I mean, how many hours I spend on a project)

edit: I once notice there is one (like a web twitter with time trace), but I forgot its name.

Answer (score 1):

If personal time tracking is what you're after, check out [Kimai](http://www.kimai.de/index.php?article_id=8&clang=1).

Answer (score 1):

On the other hand if your question is about measuring the response time of your web application, there are other proxy recorders than Firebug: SST Trace Plus and Fiddler come to mind. Fiddler is open source and you can write plug-ins for it.

If you are serious about measuring response time, you want to do it at very high loads though, to find the breaking points of your system/application. There are no good free tools, and most people use HP's LoadRunner (for large functional tests) or Spirent's Avalanche (for very high loads).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a tool to monitor you time as a developer or a tool to monitor how quickly your program responds?

If you want to track your own time, try base camp (http://www.basecamphq.com/)

If you want to monitor the performance of an app then @RichieHindle's suggestion (Firebug; answer now deleted) is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.rescuetime.com/

RescueTime Solo?